# Powershell: looping through list of names from exchange query

Tags: powershell, scripting, exchange-server-2010, powershell-5.0

My Goal is to apply a retention policy to newly created mailboxes. Details from previous article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310170/powershell-return-mailboxes-created-within-7-days-and-resides-on-specified-serve).

My Current Script code is located [here](http://pastebin.com/VhewmtqJ) for easy readability or below:

```
# Get Start Time for script timer
$startDTM = (Get-Date)

#Authenticate using cached credentials or re-prompt for credentials.
if (Test-Path C:\temp\mycred.xml) {
    $UserCredential = Import-CliXML C:\temp\mycred.xml}
else{
    Get-Credential | Export-CliXml C:\temp\mycred.xml
    $UserCredential = Import-CliXML C:\temp\mycred.xml}

#Connect to Exchange Server
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://munprdcasht04.exchange.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
    Import-PSSession $Session

#returns alias' for mailboxes where creation date is <= 7 days and
#resides on "ABC" or "DEF" server and has no retention policy applied
$NeedsRetentions = (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited| Where-Object {
    ($_.WhenCreated –ge ((Get-Date).Adddays(-7))) -and
    (($_.ServerName -like "*munprdmbxa*") -or ($_.ServerName -like "*wauprdexa*")) -and
    ($_.retentionpolicy -ne "PurgeDeletedItemsFolder_60days")} |
    ft -auto alias)  

ForEach ($NeedsRetention in $NeedsRetentions){
    set-mailbox -Identity $NeedsRetention -RetentionPolicy "PurgeDeletedItemsFolder_60days"
    }

# Get End Time
$endDTM = (Get-Date)

# Echo Time elapsed
"Elapsed Time: $(($endDTM-$startDTM).totalseconds) seconds"
```

When I echo the `$NeedsRetentions` i receive the list of AD users that i need to apply a retention policy to. But for some reason, when i loop through the the variable list with the below loop it errors out saying that the -Identity is no valid.

```
ForEach ($NeedsRetention in $NeedsRetentions){
    set-mailbox -Identity $NeedsRetention -RetentionPolicy "PurgeDeletedItemsFolder_60days"
    }
```

To troubleshoot i reduced the loop to this in order to display the individual usernames being affected by the script:

```
ForEach ($NeedsRetention in $NeedsRetentions){
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($NeedsRetention)
}
```

Doing this causes a message box to show up for every line in the variable but the string seems to be empty and thus the default message shows up on the message box.

[image]

Any ideas why `$NeedsRetention` isn't passing correctly into my loop task?

Comment: The object you stored in `NeedsRetentions` are mailboxes, the variable you are trying to pass down to `-identity` is likely to be string. I don't have this module so I can't test, but you can give this a shot `set-mailbox -Identity ($NeedsRetention).identity -RetentionPolicy "PurgeDeletedItemsFolder_60days"`

Comment: @Kai Zhao That makes sense but when i make this change i receive the following error for every mailbox listed in the variable                                      `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindingValidationException'
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Set-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : munprdcasht04.exchange.com`

Comment: `-identity` takes names right? what does `get-mailbox | get-member` look like? Should be a property there you can use.

Comment: @Kai Zhao In My experience `-identity` will take AD username, displayname, alias, or email address.  There are a to n of properties listed for that command

Comment: Any property like `email` `emailaddress` you can plugin as `($NeedsRetention).email` or `($NeedsRetention).emailaddress`? same idea, `displayname` etc would work too

Comment: @Kai Zhao those didn't work as well, i read up a little bit on these commands and as it turns out i should be able to run my query and pipe it into the Set-mailbox command like so: `Get-Mailbox | Set-mailbox -RetentionPolicy "PurgeDeletedItemsFolder_60days"` but even this is returning the error i pasted into the above comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112543/discussion-between-kai-zhao-and-mttp1990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you saved the result from a `Format-*`-cmdlet (in this case `Format-Table` by using the alias `ft`).

Never save the results from `Format-*` cmdlets to a variable. `Format-*`-cmdlets are for GUI/visual presentation only and turns your useful mailbox-objects into special format-objects that are useless for anything else then console-/file-output.

Modify:

```
$NeedsRetentions = (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited| Where-Object {
    ($_.WhenCreated –ge ((Get-Date).Adddays(-7))) -and
    (($_.ServerName -like "*munprdmbxa*") -or ($_.ServerName -like "*wauprdexa*")) -and
    ($_.retentionpolicy -ne "PurgeDeletedItemsFolder_60days")} |
    ft -auto alias)
```

To:

```
$NeedsRetentions = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited| Where-Object {
    ($_.WhenCreated –ge ((Get-Date).Adddays(-7))) -and
    (($_.ServerName -like "*munprdmbxa*") -or ($_.ServerName -like "*wauprdexa*")) -and
    ($_.retentionpolicy -ne "PurgeDeletedItemsFolder_60days")}
```

If you want to output the `$NeedsRetentions`-objects to the console before continuing with modifying the mailboxes, then do that as a separate command (without saving the format-output). Ex:

```
$NeedsRetentions | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: re-running now, fingers crossed

Comment: Good luck. Btw. When developing scripts, run them against a few users only to test (ex by adding a filter for username). It saves time and does less damage if it doesn't work.

Comment: thank you, normally i run this type of stuff in a specific OU to limit impact to the environment. you will likely see me on her more often, so until next time...

Comment: Btw. Didn't notice the alias property, so unless `set-mailbox` picks out the right identity property auto. (which I think it does), then just modify it to ex. `set-mailbox -identity $needsretention.alias .....`

Comment: I already had a loop in place to apply the change. Just passing the identity was the issue.